# Unusual memory usage in LinearModelFit in version 11.1

Tags: bugs, fitting, memory

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

I recently installed MMA v11.1 and encountered an issue with the memory usage of the LinearModelFit[] command. It appears than when mixing numeric and nominal variables, the LinearModelFit[] command uses a very large block of memory. I first noticed with issue on a large Linux server, where the the MMA kernel kept crashing after consuming all 256 GB of memory for a relatively small problem.

I created a simple example in an attempt to illustrate the problem:

```
In[44]:= $Version

Out[44]= "11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"
```

First create a simple data matrix of size *n*:

```
regDat[n_] := Transpose[{
    RandomChoice[{"Yes", "No"}, n],  (* nominal variable *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],  (* numeric #1 *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],  (* numeric #2 *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n]  (* dependent variable *)
    }
   ];
```

Now run a regression with *n* = 25,000, using only the numeric variables:

```
mem1 = MaxMemoryUsed[
   LinearModelFit[regDat[25000], {v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, 
    NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}]] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.10582, 8813008}
```

This uses about 8.8 MB of memory. Now run the same regression, except add the nominal variable (which has values {"Yes","No"}):

```
mem2 = MaxMemoryUsed[
   LinearModelFit[regDat[25000], {v1Nom, v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, 
    NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}]] // AbsoluteTiming

{6.92887, 4120980912}
```

This new regression takes 65x longer and uses 4.12 GB of memory.

I've confirmed this behavior on v11.1 on Windows and Linux. My original problem had *n*=257,000 observations, with 6 numeric variables and 4 nominal variables, and was unable to run due to excessive memory usage. But the same code ran without issue on v10 and v11.

(Note: The only time I've encountered memory issues using the LinearModelFit[] command is when I've inadvertently treated a numeric value as a nominal. I'm speculating that perhaps v 11.1 is treating all variables as nominal when a regression has a both types).

Can anyone else confirm this behavior?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I get the same results on Windows 7 with *Mathematica* versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 (with a deviation in the code in that that I think you must have not used `NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}` in `mem1`.)  The solution is for large datasets to avoid `NominalVariables` and create your own dummy variables.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues using your code with *Mathematica* versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 (but removing `NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}` on `mem1`):

```
regDat[n_] := 
  Transpose[{RandomChoice[{"Yes", "No"}, n],(*nominal variable*)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],(*numeric #1*)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],(*numeric #2*)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n]  (*dependent variable*)}];

data = regDat[25000];

mem1 = MaxMemoryUsed[LinearModelFit[data, {v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.1282489100989303`, 6409488} *)

mem2 = MaxMemoryUsed[
   LinearModelFit[data, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, 
    NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.661942728611961`, 4120505936} *)
```

A workaround for large datasets is to create your own dummy variables:

```
data = data /. {"Yes" -> 1, "No" -> 0};
mem3 = MaxMemoryUsed[LinearModelFit[data, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.19569940752999232`,11740464} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with posting this question, I also filed a ticket with WRI technical support. They confirmed this behavior under MMA v11.1.0.

With the release of MMA v11.1.1 on April 18, 2017, this bug has been resolved:

```
In[11]:= $Version

Out[11]= "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"

regDat[n_] := Transpose[{
    RandomChoice[{"Yes", "No"}, n],  (* nominal variable *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],  (* numeric #1 *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n],  (* numeric #2 *)
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, n]  (* dependent variable *)}
];
```

Using only numeric variables gives:

```
In[13]:= MaxMemoryUsed[
  LinearModelFit[
   regDat[25000], {v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[13]= {0.110184, 6613256}
```

So the `LinearModelFit` command uses about 6.6 Mb of memory. Now add a nominal variable

```
In[14]:= MaxMemoryUsed[
  LinearModelFit[regDat[25000], {v1Nom, v2, v3}, {v1Nom, v2, v3}, 
   NominalVariables -> {v1Nom}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[14]= {0.309891, 21218712}
```

The regression uses 21.2Mb of memory, a much more reasonable amount.